Is there anything like a poll on the most plausible or convincing arguments for believing in God's existence?
This video presents a tier list ranking seven philosophical arguments:

The Contingency Argument
The Kalam Cosmological Argument
The Anselmian Ontological Argument
The Modal Ontological Argument
The Fine-Tuning Argument
The Moral Argument
The Argument from the Resurrection of Jesus

However, the rankings in this tier list reflect the opinions of only the two individuals in the video. I’m looking for a more authoritative source, such as the results of a broader poll or a survey paper that synthesizes the literature on these sorts of arguments. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

These guys also compiled a tier list of arguments against God:

The Problem of Evil
Divine Hiddenness
Religious Confusion
The Stone Paradox
The Scale of the Universe
The Evil God Challenge
The Improvability Argument
The Argument from Material Causality
The Modal Argument From Evil


I think you'd need to look for something related but different for it to mean much of anything. Nobody believes most of what they believe because they were convinced by philosophical arguments, and most people believe none of what they believe because they were convinced by philosophical arguments, including some of the people who believe that they believe some of what they believe because they were convinced by philosophical arguments.

Do you really think that we will decide about G's existence using a poll?

@MauroALLEGRANZA I never said that I thought so.

@user80226 Possibly you like to take a short look at the list from https://survey2020.philpeople.org/survey/results/4842

Charles Taylor, in A Secular Age, argued that it is none of those "arguments" that is the primary rationale for those who hold a religious view, but is instead the problems with a "disenchanted" worldview.  https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/a-secular-age/
Explicitly, he thinks the issue is one of the comparative flaws between two worldviews.  And the problem with a "naturalist" worldview is the lack of "transcendence" being compatible with it.  The aspects of transcendence that attract people to religion include:  selfhood, agency, free will, relationships, values, virtues, and the reality of morality.  This is compared to the mechanistic, mind-free, values-free, willing-free worldview that one ends up with when one accepts Descartes dualism, then declares the mental part of that dualism to be nonexistent/irrelevant, leaving only mechanism in the world.
The problem for the religious POV is the power/success of a mechanistic worldview, and the "irrelevancy" of everything under the categories of enchantment and transcendence when one applies careful reasoning and empirical testing to them.
Taylor considers both POVs to be intrinsically psychologically unstable for those who hold by them.

"Points of View Considered Harmful" :-)

Is it an example of the "power/success of a mechanistic worldview" that the portion of humanity which subscribes to this worldview is now undergoing the biggest natural demographic implosion of all times?

I love how your answer resonates so much with me without feeling like you're explicitly siding with one particular view. Scientifically, I see no justification for "free will" as a meaningful concept (i.e., unless one defines away what a layperson might actually consider to be free will). Personally? I like to say, "I'm predestined to believe I possess free will." That's more of a joke than anything though, because I don't know that I do believe that.

@vsz I at least do not consider that to be a negative at all.  Humans and our domestic animals make up 96% of the mammal biomass.  We are so close to ecosystem collapse due to destruction of supporting ecological niches, that we absolutely need to reduce our numbers, or Darwin will do it for us.

@BenHocking Thanks for the praise.  Taylor notes that most people try to break the either/or of these competing worldviews, and find ways to bring values and consciousness/agency into a "naturalist" worldview (example, Karl Popper's Triplism, with emergent dualism), or extending naturalism into "transcendent" subjects (examples: psi researchers, or adopting pluralism in science plus non-science knowledge).  I have a POV, and it is on the transcendent side, where I extend methodological naturalism into spirituality.  These alternative efforts are slowly gaining ground vs the two dominant ones.

@BenHocking -- Note that our world is not fully deterministic, but only mostly deterministic.  This is one of three preconditions for libertarian free will.  Also, compatibilism actually makes a lot more sense in an only partially determined world, as a "determined" control system "will" is then needed to deal with open-ended surprising events.  See this question, and the compatibilist and libertarian answers that tkruse and I offered:  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/113255/the-evolution-of-free-will-is-kevin-mitchells-argument-robust/113294#113294

Mainstream survey organizations like Pew don't seem to enter into that level of granularity, and survey's of such positions don't seem to be conducted as surveys. If you can't find anything and haven't checked yet, you might be more productive by looking at PhilPapers.org. They aspire to be a comprehensive repository of documents.
I ran a search for "poll arguments for against God" and came up with an abstract of a book from CUP entitled Logic and Theism: Arguments for and Against Beliefs in God.. It might the sort of resource that has what you're looking for as an ancillary to the thesis of the text.
A better lead might be Inventing American Religion which is listed on Google Scholar. It seems to be a poll-centric effort. From the abstract:

oday, a billion-dollar-a-year polling industry floods the media with information. Pollsters tell us not only which political candidates will win, but how we are practicing our faith. How many Americans went to church last week? Have they been born again? Is Jesus as popular as Harry Potter? Polls tell us that 40 percent of Americans attend religious services each week. They show that African Americans are no more religious than white Americans, and that Jews are abandoning their religion in record numbers. According to leading sociologist Robert Wuthnow, none of that is correct. Pollsters say that attendance at religious services has been constant for decades.

What you are asking for is rather niche, so if you come across it, be sure to post your find here! It would be the sort of materials that would be worth skimming even if it's out of a person's particular philosophical focus. Good luck.
